# Powershell script convert to html and change font/cell color based on number threshold

Tags: html, css, powershell

I have a simple powershell script that runs several queries against a list of servers getting cpu, disk, and mem counters. Im importing the csv when its populated and converting to html.. also using css in the script to color the rows but i want to highlight and cell or text in RED if its above 80 or below 5.
Here is the CSS portion of the code and importing the CSV..

```
$css = @"
<style>
h1, h5, th { text-align: center; font-family: Segoe UI; }
table { margin: auto; font-family: Segoe UI; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; border: thin ridge grey; }
th { background: #0046c3; color: #fff; max-width: 400px; padding: 5px 10px; }
td { font-size: 11px; padding: 5px 20px; color: #000; }
tr { background: #b8d1f3; }
tr:nth-child(even){ background: #dae5f4; }
</style>
"@

Import-CSV "health.csv" | ConvertTo-Html -Head $css -Body "<h1>Email Report</h1>`n<h5>Generated on $(Get-Date)</h5>" | Out-File "health.html"
```

is it possible when using convert to html?

Here is a sample of the CSV

```
"Server","CPU","MemFreeGB","CFreeGB","FFreeGB"
server1, 14.72, 17.18, 52.79, 80.42
server2, 0.2, 28.95, 59.86, 77.15
server3, 30.23, 13.5, 54.47, 83.14
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the lines in your .csv file?

Comment: updated post with csv sample

Comment: In your PowerShell logic when you build the webpage document, you could use tag based CSS formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet, in this case you could use a dedicated custom function to create the html table that allows you to add extra style to the cells.

Try this:

```
function ConvertTo-HTMLTable ($obj) {
    # add type needed to replace HTML special characters into entities
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

    $sb = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('<table>')
    if ($null -ne $obj) {
        $headers = $obj[0].PSObject.Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('<thead><tr>')
        foreach ($column in $headers) {
            [void]$sb.Append(('<th>{0}</th>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($column)))
        }
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr></thead><tbody>')
        [double]$num = 0
        $obj | ForEach-Object {
            foreach ($column in $headers) {
                [string]$val = $_.$column
                # test if $val contains a number, and if so check if it is less than 5 or greater than 80
                if ([double]::TryParse($val, [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::Float, 
                                       [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [ref]$num)) {
                    # it's a numeric value, see it we need to change color
                    $td = if ($num -gt 80 -or $num -lt 5) {"<td style=color:red;>$val</td>"} else {"<td>$val</td>"}
                }
                elseif ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($val)) { 
                    $td = '<td>&nbsp;</td>' 
                } 
                else { 
                    $td = '<td>{0}</td>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($val)
                }
                [void]$sb.Append($td)
            }
            [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr>')
        }
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tbody>')
    }
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('</table>')

    return $sb.ToString()
}



$css = @"
<style>
h1, h5, th, td { text-align: center; font-family: Segoe UI; }
table { margin: auto; font-family: Segoe UI; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; border: thin ridge grey; }
th { background: #0046c3; color: #fff; max-width: 400px; padding: 5px 10px; }
td { font-size: 11px; padding: 5px 20px; color: #000; }
tr { background: #b8d1f3; }
tr:nth-child(even){ background: #dae5f4; }
</style>
"@

$body  = "<h1>Email Report</h1>`r`n<h5>Generated on $(Get-Date)</h5>"
$table = ConvertTo-HTMLTable (Import-CSV "D:\health.csv")
$html  = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Report</title>
<meta name="generator" content="PowerShell" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
$css
</head>
<body>
$body
$table
</body></html>
"@

$html | Out-File "D:\health.html" -Force
```

Result:

[image]